# How to extract every second value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Hello I need make a function that will console.log every second value from array. 
So if we have

```js
var someArray = [1,45,65,98,321,8578,orange,onion];
```

Then console.log will return 45,98,8578,onion...somebody have any ideas how to do it please ?

Comment: just a little bit of research should have given you at least a starting point towards solving this yourself

Comment: Actually cant find anything about it for two days :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array#filter` to remove unwanted items based on their index.

Only items that have a truthy division remainder will be returned to the new array containing your values.

```js
var someArray = [1,45,65,98,321,8578,'orange','onion'];

console.log(
  someArray.filter((x, i) => i % 2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop to display every other items in the array (starting at position 1):

```
var everySecondValue = function (array) {
  for (i=1; i <= array.length-1; i+=2) {
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
}

everySecondValue([1,45,65,98,321,8578,"orange","onion"]);
```